# CSS navigation: two submenus side by side

Tags: css, menu

It's difficult to explain... Please have a look:

https://codepen.io/bigfraggle/pen/XBpEYY

In want the two columns within navigation 2 side by side without any margin. I've tried floating both  but this doesn't work. The

```
style="left: 84px;"
```

for the right column isn't a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`float: left;` and `position: absolute;` do not work together.
Try giving the blocks a relative position and add `float: left;` to both columns.

If you need the blocks to be positioned absolute, place them in a surrounding `div`. Give this div `position: absolute;` and the other styles needed for positioning. This way you can keep your columns relative.

Based on your new fiddle [here](https://codepen.io/bigfraggle/pen/pZRVrO), to place both columns in the submenu next to each other, follow these steps:

Remove `width: 200%;` from the new div:

```
<div style="position: absolute; background: yellow;">
```

Remove `float: left;` from the columns:

```
#navi li ul {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    /*float: left;*/
    left: -1px;
    padding: 0;
    background: #222B38;
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #FFFFFF; 
}
```

Add `display: table-cell;` to the columns:

```
#navi li:hover ul,
#navi a:hover ul {
    display: table-cell; 
}
```

`float: left;` will always **try** to place elements next to each other, but had no problem placing them under each other when there isn't enough space. This gives problems when you don't know how wide your wrapper is. `display: table-cell` however will work in these situations.

Comment: Ok, that was easy and I've updated the linked pen above.

Now when hovering navigation 2 it becomes wider. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: I've tried an additional div with `position: absolute` here:

https://codepen.io/bigfraggle/pen/pZRVrO

There I have a problem with the dynamic width of this div...